# How to add leftover values

Tags: php, mysql

```
$get_data = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE x < max_x and y < max_y";
$get_data_query = mysqli_query($conn,$get_data);

while ($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_data_query)) {

    $update = "UPDATE stats SET 
                                x = x + (max_x / 11.11111111111111),
                                y = y + (max_y / 11.11111111111111)

              WHERE id = '".$data['id']."' ";

              mysqli_query($conn,$update); }
```

In the above data, I've a code to determine max_x and max_y values for each user 
I am trying to use this above code as "cron job"

but there's one issue with it.
Let's consider Case 1 :
 max_x = 600, max_y = 100 
and if I run this code 11 times, it will look like this

```
 ==>  X/Y

1 ==> 54/9

2 ==> 108/18

3 ==> 162/27

4 ==> 216/36

5 ==> 270/45

6 ==> 324/54

7 ==> 378/63

8 ==> 432/72

9 ==> 486/81

10 ==> 540/90

11 ==> 594/99
```

Case 2 : max_x = 1200, max_y = 200

```
...11 ==> 1188/198
```

So how do I make sure that X = +6 and Y = +1 is added in this Case 1 

and X = +12 and Y = +2 in Case 2

As in, how do I make sure that "leftover" values are added without crossing the max_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the calculation part in php where it is easier (and more appropriate) to implement the program logic then simply pass the new values to the update script.

```
$get_data = "SELECT * FROM stats WHERE x < max_x and y < max_y";
$get_data_query = mysqli_query($conn,$get_data);

 while ($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_data_query)) {
    // added one-liners if you want a bit cleaner code
    // $x_new = $x + ($max_x / 11.11111111111111) < $max_x ? x + (max_x / 11.11111111111111) : $max_x;
    // $y_new = $y + ($max_y / 11.11111111111111) < $max_y ? y + (max_y / 11.11111111111111) : $max_x;
    $x_new = $x + ($max_x / 11.11111111111111);
    if ($x_new > $max_x) { 
        $x_new = $max_x;   
    } 
    $y_new = $y + ($max_y / 11.11111111111111);
    if ($y_new > $max_y) { 
        $y_new = $max_y;   
    } 
    $update = "UPDATE stats SET 
                                x = '".$x_new."',
                                y = '".$y_new."'

              WHERE id = '".$data['id']."' ";

              mysqli_query($conn,$update); }
```

Comment: Undefined variable x_new and y_new @Simas Joneliunas

Comment: updated the code. mixed up different naming strategies when writing the answer...

Comment: Again, fixed a few missing `$` signs - maybe that was the issue. Sorry for lousy typing ~~

Comment: Yeah, I used different variable instead of $data and the whole thing got messed up, but thanks its working fine now.